# Does an aesthetic dichotomy between universalism and relativism occur widely cross-culturally?

Tags: aesthetics, philosophy-of-culture

Roughly speaking, there appears to be a recurrent attitude some people have about what intrinsically separates “good art” from some intrinsically held reason some art is not good. We can imagine such an attitude held strongly enough might even describe it disparagingly and in a devaluing way, like saying it’s “garbage”, for example.

Some people, and some philosophies, might argue that aesthetic experiences are completely relativistic and there is no intrinsic or absolute worthiness of any aesthetic object over another. Furthermore, as I hold, the category of “aesthetic” or “art” seems very local, particular and culturally limited, arbitrary and non-necessary.

Does the tendency to see some people within a culture select certain art practices as inherently “worthy” in some way, occur in many cultures? In other words, could it be specific to, say, “Western” culture, or, certain kinds of societies, like ones that have evolved traditional or “elevated” art forms over generations, like Chinese, Indian, Indonesian, European, etc., to see some people believe in a kind of inherent/absolutist aesthetic judgment, or is this common enough that it could be by dint of human psychology that people or culture often has this inertia, perhaps to *reify* aesthetic experiences, epistemologically, morally, etc.?

In other words, in myriad cultures, we could witness that culture’s variant or equivalent of those who believe dogmatically in an aesthetic “correctness”, *and* those who may critique that and advocate a kind of *laissez faire* view on aesthetics, just as one may draw parallels in various cultures in things like religious or mystical experiences, or anything else which seems to recur cross-culturally.

**Is an aesthetic universal-relativistic dichotomy, itself universal, or itself culturally relative?**